# Rails: Issues with time calculations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, activesupport

I would venture that this is an issue with my environment, not ActiveSupport...

Regardless of the method being called (ago,  from_now, etc), I get the same error, where x represents today's date, e.g. July 23 = 23.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `advance' for "x":String
```

So, `1.day` gives me:

```
86400
```

However, `1.day.ago` gives me:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `advance' for "23":String
```

The backtrace:

```
activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:101:in `advance'
```

Has anyone seen this behavior?

Comment: try to reinstall rails

Comment: Let me mention that I am seeing the exact same behavior on Heroku.

Comment: If anyone cares, I determined the issue not be the environment, nor the Gemfile. I had defined several additional methods for Time and DateTime for ease of returning formatted dates/times; e.g. my_date.to_full_words. One or more of these methods were overriding default DateTime/Time methods. By simply re-prefixing my methods from to_method_name to as_method_name the problem went away.